# nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)

Tags: docker, nginx, grafana

I have the following docker file

```
FROM grafana/grafana
EXPOSE 8080 8080
COPY config /config
COPY start-nginx-grafana.sh /start-nginx-grafana.sh
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
RUN chown -R grafana:grafana /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /var/log/nginx /var/lib/nginx /start-nginx-grafana.sh
RUN chmod +x /start-nginx-grafana.sh /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /var/log/nginx /var/lib/nginx
USER grafana
RUN cp /config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ENTRYPOINT [ "/start-nginx-grafana.sh" ]
```

when I built it and tried to run a container, it runs without issues, but I could not access a website behind an Nginx proxy so I checked the docker logs, and I found

```
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

and my Nginx config's as follows

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        listen 3001;
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                proxy_pass                            http://localhost:3000/;
                proxy_set_header Host                 $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-WEBAUTH-USER       "";
                }
        }
    server {
        listen 8080;
        location / {
                proxy_pass                            http://localhost:3000/;
                proxy_set_header Host                 $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-WEBAUTH-USER       "guest";
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix *nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)* and what I did wrong.

Comment: I'd typically run Grafana and Nginx in separate containers, which would avoid this specific issue.  (And you should be able to notice immediately on startup that the Nginx container is failing without affecting the Grafana container.)

Comment: You could try to change the User in nginx.conf to grafana, and then run the nginx server as grafana as well. Might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you run all your processes with the user `grafana`

the warning state : that the main `nginx` process is not a super user.

`grafana` user does not have access to the file `/var/run/nginx.pid` .

I suggest you to remove `USER grafana` from your `Dockerfile` and run your `grafana` in your script with command :

```
runuser -l grafana -c "...."
```